# Pandas apply labels from df1 to df2 if values are within a range in df1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, df1 and df2. df1 is a table of labels set between ranges:

```
    Top    Bottom    Label    ID
0   0.0    2.2       A        Z-1
1   2.2    6.6       B        Z-1
2   6.6    9.1       C        Z-1
3   0.0    1.2       A        Z-2
4   1.2    4.5       B        Z-2
5   6.6    9.1       C        Z-2
```

Where the ID column relates to a higher order grouping. Both df1 and df2 contain shared ID's and I want to apply the labels from df1 to df2.

df2 is a table of regularly sampled data:

```
    Samp   Var    ID
0   0.0    157    Z-1
1   0.5    226    Z-1
2   1.5    843    Z-1
3   2.0    999    Z-1
4   2.5    142    Z-1
5   3.0    167    Z-1
6   0.0    157    Z-2
7   0.5    226    Z-2
8   1.5    111    Z-2
9   2.0    666    Z-3
```

The desired output would look like this:

```
    Samp   Var    ID    Label
0   0.0    157    Z-1   A
1   0.5    226    Z-1   A
2   1.5    843    Z-1   A
3   2.0    999    Z-1   A
4   2.5    142    Z-1   B
5   3.0    167    Z-1   B
6   0.0    157    Z-2   A
7   0.5    226    Z-2   A
8   1.5    111    Z-2   B
9   2.0    666    Z-3   B
```

The issue I am having when looking for other answers is that I first need to match the ID's and then apply the labels within the range between the top and bottom columns. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand the logic. Why is there no label C in the desired output? Why does the record with ID `Z-3` have label `B` in the output?

Comment: Ah I see that the value for `Samp` is used to figure out which label you need (by boundaries `Top` and `Bottom`. But my last question is still unanswered

Comment: @8556732, added a solution. does it answer your question?

Comment: Hey sorry for the slow reply - that's just a subset/example of the data. C would exist in df2, just in more rows (the real data has ~10k rows)

Comment: @Naveed's solution below works really nicely. Sorry for not explaining the problem better Tobias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way to do it
Z-3 doesn't exists in your reference table and hence its null.

Idea is to merge on ID and then query the ones where Samp falls within the range, and then its just a cleanup of result set

```
df2.merge(df, on='ID', how='left', suffixes=("","_y")
         ).query('(Samp>=Top & Samp<=Bottom) | Label.isna()'
                ).reset_index().drop(
                                columns=['index','Top','Bottom']
)
```

```
    Samp    Var     ID  Label
0   0.0     157     Z-1     A
1   0.5     226     Z-1     A
2   1.5     843     Z-1     A
3   2.0     999     Z-1     A
4   2.5     142     Z-1     B
5   3.0     167     Z-1     B
6   0.0     157     Z-2     A
7   0.5     226     Z-2     A
8   1.5     111     Z-2     B
9   2.0     666     Z-3     NaN
```